# White list ip range for connecting from ADF to Snowflake

Tags: ip, azure-data-factory, whitelist

We have a client that has data in Snowflake, but also limits IP connectivity to the data warehouse.  If we are going to use the default Azure Data Factory Snowflake connector, what IP's do we have to give the client to whitelist?  Is it the entire range from the datacenter location?  I understand we may be able to run the ADF in a separate vnet, but don't want to add that to the deployment.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SHIR for connectivity then you can whitelist your SHIR machine IP address.

In case if you would want to use a custom Azure Intergration Runtime specific to a region then you need to whiltelist the complete Azure IR IP range of that region.

In case if you are using default Azure IR then you will have to whitelist the complete Azure IR IP range.

You can get an IP range list of service tags from the service tags IP range [download link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/service-tags-overview#discover-service-tags-by-using-downloadable-json-files). For example, if the Azure region is AustraliaEast, you can get an IP range list from DataFactory.AustraliaEast. For more info please refer here - [Azure Integration Runtime IP addresses: Specific regions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/azure-integration-runtime-ip-addresses#azure-integration-runtime-ip-addresses-specific-regions)